# How do i sum my array result together

Tags: php, arrays, session

How do I get the result of my array in total?
I have tried:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && is_array($_SESSION["cart_array"])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $id  = $each_item["item_id"];
        $qty = $each_item["quantity"];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code='$id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $price     = $row["price"];
            $cartTotal = $price * $qty;
            echo "$cartTotal,";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Please be more precise in your question. What do you want do sum up? Where do you want to sum it? SQL? PHP?

Comment: what u actually want to achieve? please explain your code

Comment: Please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/1415724) and the [help area](https://stackoverflow.com/help) if you haven't already.

Comment: My $_SESSION["cart_array"] result i cant format over here please use edit

Comment: If you want to sum alle "carTotal" prices -> create a variable (=0) above the foreach and add every result to it.

Comment: Going out on a limb here, I think what you want is `$cartTotal += $price * $qty;` instead of `$cartTotal = $price * $qty;`

Comment: I want to get the total result for $cartTotal = $price * $qty; couse it output 624 instead of 12 i just want to result to output 12 if my result for $cartTotal = $price * $qty; is 624